# How to assign QAbstractListModel to ListModel

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel, listmodel

I have an application which contains ListModel. I have written C++ class derived from QAbstractListModel.

QML List model looks like

```
// SelectedStepsModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    ListElement{
        step_name:""
        step_icon:""
```

and, C++ class looks like

```
class ProductModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString product_name READ get_product_name)

public:
    enum {
        StepNameRole = Qt::UserRole,
        StepIconRole,
        ...
```

In main,

```
...
        ProductModel* product_model = new ProductModel();
        context->setContextProperty("product_model", QVariant::fromValue(product_model));
...
```

In one of the files (where QML model gets filled by some functions in QML) I want to replace that logic with newly created model ( as model has all data ).

```
// some other file

    SelectedStepsModel {
        id: selected_model
    }

    selected_model = product_model
```

Note, here selected_model is ListModel and product_model is QAbstractListModel.
But selected_model = product_model is failing.

Am I doing the right thing else what is the correct way of assigning QAbstractListModel to ListModel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't be done, why don't you set `product_model` directly in view?: `View{model: product_model}`

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "assigning" the models here: either you use the model instance that you declared in QML, or you use the model you provided. Choose one or the other.